# Express, Mongoose : OverwriteModelError : Cannot Overwrite 'xxxxx' model once compiled

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm encoutering an error when using a Mongoose Model in my program.

I've did that in the beginning of my code :

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('xxxxx');
```

I used a first schema called userSchema to connect/sign up a user.

I've this code, which should do a random on the field Bonus of my DB. But when I go to the randTest page, I have this error. How can I fix it ?

```
app.get('/randTest', function(req,res) 
{
 var bonusSchema = new Schema({ 
 bonus : [String]
 });

var bonusModel = mongoose.model('Plateau', bonusSchema);  

var query = bonusModel.find(null);  
query.exec(function (err, allBonus){  
 if(err) { throw err;}

 var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() *allBonus.length)); 
 var result = allBonus[rand-1];        

});
res.render('randTest', {result: result});
});
```

In my Jade file I've just :

```
extends layout

block content

 script.
  alert({#result});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `bonusModel` definition outside of `app.get` so that it's only called once:

```
var bonusSchema = new Schema({ 
  bonus : [String]
});

var bonusModel = mongoose.model('Plateau', bonusSchema);  

app.get('/randTest', function(req,res) 
{
  var query = bonusModel.find(null);
  ...
});
```